# Cannot convert String to DOM in Java

Tags: java, dom, response, scribe

Here is the code:

```
Response resp = tkMarC.getClock(TK_Base.Format.xml);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();        
String xml = resp.getBody();
System.out.println(xml);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);
try {
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();                
    Document docu = db.parse(is);
    if (docu != null)
    {
        NodeList nl = docu.getChildNodes();
        for(int i=0; i<nl.getLength(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(nl.item(i).toString());
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

And here is the output from System.out.println(xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response id="-5b6df009:14ebc2afaf9:-3779">
  <date>2015-07-23 14:30:25.134000</date>
  <status>
        <current>open</current>
        <next>after</next>
        <change_at>16:00:00</change_at>
    </status>
  <message>Market is open</message>
  <unixtime>1437676225</unixtime>
</response>
```

However the 
sr object always shows:
The length of the characterstream is 307 but str is null
docu object always shows: 
docu = (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl) [#document: null]

and hence no ChildNodes are retrievable as this is what gets output:
[response: null] on console when code enters the for loop on i=0

What am I missing here? I also tried to convert the message to a byte stream via ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()); and pass that in as an input source but got the same result there is something I guess I don't quite grasp and was unable to find searching the forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. Your code works fine. You're only confused by the `toString()` of your element. The `toString()` of an element will show the tag name followed by the node value. For elements, the node value is null, hence you get `[response: null]`.

Seen in NodeImpl.class:

```
/** NON-DOM method for debugging convenience. */
public String toString() {
    return "["+getNodeName()+": "+getNodeValue()+"]";
}
```

So you're getting your top element, `response`, properly.

Comment: You are right but all Nodes return a value of Null for some reason shouldn't the element for instance: <current> return open for its node value? I get the following for each: 
Node Name:current Node Value:null
When I change the code to NodeList nl = docu.getElementsByTagName("current");
                for(int i=0; i<nl.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Node Name:" + nl.item(i).getNodeName() + "\tNode Value:" + nl.item(i).getNodeValue());
                }

Comment: Ok nevermind I need to use getTextContent and not getNodeValue to retrieve the value within the node element. Little bit confusing but hey now I know better thanks for the quick answer I will mark yours as correct.